# $H$ is normal subgroup of $G$ iff $gHg^{-1}=H$ for every $g$ of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, normal-subgroups

Given the following definition of normal subgroup

> *A subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is said to be normal if, for every $g\in G$: $$gH=Hg$$*

I've tried to show that $H\mathrel{\unlhd} G$ if and only if we have $gHg^{-1}=H$ for every $g\in G$:

(if) Let $H\mathrel{\unlhd} G$, $g\in G$; if $l\in gHg^{-1}$, there exists $h\in H$ such that $l=ghg^{-1}$ and since $gh$ = $h'g$ for some $h'\in H$, then $l=ghg^{-1}=h'(gg^{-1}) = h'\in H$. Let $h\in H$; we can write $h$ as $hgg^{-1}$, and since $hg = gh'$ for some $h'\in H$, we obtain $h = hgg^{-1} = gh'g^{-1}\in ghg^{-1}$. So $gHg^{-1}=H$.

(only if) Let $gHg^{-1}=H$, $g\in G$; if we take an $l\in Hg$, $l = hg$ for some $h\in H$, we note immediately that $l=hg=(gh'g^{-1})g=gh'\in gH$. **What should I do to show that $gH\subset Hg$**?

I'm also wondering if this mess is correct, and if it is possible a more elegant proof of this fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have proved that $Hg\subseteq gH$.  One might say "by symmetry" the other direction holds, or just prove it directly, using basically the same argument:

Let $m\in gH$ be arbitrary.  Then $m=gh$ for some $h\in H$.  Now $mg^{-1}=ghg^{-1}=h'$, for some $h'\in H$.  Hence $m=h'g$, so $m\in Hg$.  This proves that $gH\subseteq Hg$.

Answer (score 4):

I think a more elegant proof is possible.

Clearly $gHg^{-1}=H\iff gHg^{-1}g=Hg\iff gHe=Hg\iff gH=Hg, \forall g\in G$, simply by multiplying by $g$ on the right (and simplifying $g^{-1}g=e$ and $He=H$).

Comment: It's more elegant, definitely.

Comment: This is nice, but the first double-headed arrow is only "clear" in the forward direction; the reverse takes some justification.

Comment: In the forward statement, we can also note that is sufficient to prove that $gHg^{-1}\subset H$, for all $g\in G$: if this holds, then taken $h\in H$ and $g_0\in G$, we have $h' = g_0^{-1}hg_0 \in H$, and so $h = g_0h'g_0^{-1} \in g_0Hg_0^{-1}$; this is true for all $g_0$s, since the original choice of that element is arbitrary. I found this way to write down the proof more readable, in fact by expanding it doing all passages, it turns exactly in the proof of the op. (Or it is possible that I didn't get where the inverse is not clear)